# In Java, why would a variable declared in both a parent and child class be invisible in an instance of the child class?

Tags: java, inheritance

Specifically, why would a variable declared in both a parent and child class be invisible in an instance of the child class passed to a method where the argument is the parent class?

Here is a simplified example of an issue that's puzzling me. There are three classes, a parent and two child subtypes. The classes have a Foo object as a field and this static sort of factory method:

```
class Parent {
    public Foo myFoo;

    public static ThinChild createThinChild(Foo someFoo) {
        ThinChild thinChild = new ThinChild(someFoo);
        return thinChild;
    }

    public Foo getFoo() {
        return myFoo;
    }
}

class ThinChild extends Parent {
    public Foo myFoo;

    public ThinChild(Foo someFoo) {
        myFoo = someFoo;
    }
}

class ThickChild extends Parent {
    public Foo myFoo;

    public ThickChild(Foo someFoo) {
        myFoo = someFoo;
    }
}
```

Now consider this handler class:

```
class ChildHandler {
    private void doSomethingToThinChild(ThinChild thinChild) {
        assert(thinChild.getFoo() != null);
        doSomethingToAllChildren(thinChild);
    }

    private void doSomethingToAllChildren(Parent thinOrThickChild) {
        assert(thinOrThickChild.getFoo() != null);
    }
}
```

When I call `doSomethingToThinChild`, the assert passes. But in the method `doSomethingToAllChildren`, the assert fails. This is not what I expect.

Moreover, if I add the same exact `getFoo` method that's in the `Parent` class to my `ThinChild` class, the assert now works. Which solves my immediate problem but seems undesirable to me insofar as I'm now maintaining identical code in each of the child classes where I'd prefer just to maintain it in the parent.

My actual case is a bit more complicated, but I hope I've captured all the relevant details. Assuming that I have, is there any explanation for why this would be expected behavior?

It is possible that there's an additional complication in my actual code that I haven't represented here. But I'd first like to confirm that my understanding of class inheritance in Java is sound.

Thanks.

Comment: you mean `class ThinChild extends Parent`?

Comment: you don't need to declare 
    `public Foo myFoo;` in nested classes. myFoo is there already

Comment: The three classes are completely unrelated. No class extends any other one. And the handler doesn't compile.

Comment: Yes, `ThinChild` and `ThickChild` extend `Parent` -- a transcription error. I was simplifying my actual code.

Comment: remove `public Foo myFoo;` in nested classes. this field extends from parent class

Comment: @JB-Nizet Consider this pseudo-code. It isn't meant to compile. As noted, I'm trying to represent the essential factors that describe my more complicated real-world case.

Comment: @klenwell: discussing the behavior of code that doesn't compile doesn't make any sense. Post an SSCCE, and we'll explain why it behaves how it behaves. The only thing I can say is that the two assertions of your handler do the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `public Foo myFoo`. In nested classes, this field extends from parent class. You can't change it because you have 2 variables with same name. So JVM initialized the variable with the smaller scope.

Also the good way is to create constructor in parent:

```
public Parent(Foo someFoo) {
    myFoo = someFoo;
}
```

and then call it in subclasses:

```
public ThinChild(Foo someFoo) {
    super(someFoo);
}
```

Comment: Removing field declaring in child class solved my problem. Thanks. But I can't see why it matters. Can you update your answer to emphasize that point and help me understand why it matters if possible?

Comment: variable myFoo is not visible from nested classes, you can't change it because you have 2 variables with same name. So JVM initialized variable with smaller scope

Comment: Thanks @alaster. Edited your answer to include your comments and selected it.

Answer (score 1):

myFoo is visible from direct child classes, you just have to qualify it with a "super.myFoo".  This only works going 1 level up the chain though. so if ThinChild had a subclass ThinnerChild with a myFoo as well, you could not get to instance of "myFoo" which lives in the Parent class.  The idea being that you should be able to override your own behavior with your parents, but you should not be able to override your parent (hence why something like super.super is not allowed).

That being said, removing the instances on the child class is most likely what you want, since each ThinChild and ThickChild effectively has two "myFoo" instances in this case, one belonging to it, and one to it's parent.